# Is there a way to farm DNA?

Tags: jurassic-world-the-game

There are three achievements concerning DNA

- Stranded Part 1 - Hold 1,000 DNA
- Stranded Part 2 - Hold 20,000 DNA
- Stranded Part 3 - Hold 60,000 DNA

As far as I know we can get DNA from card packs, by selling dinosaurs or by watching ads. Is there any technique to farm DNA to unlock those achievements faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get DNA from:

- Opening card packs - every 6h you get a free one, it is not guaranteed that you'll get DNA but the chances of getting some DNA are very good.
- Arena reward - Every time you win an arena fight you get the chance to spin a wheel of rewards. You might get some DNA. It costs 5 cash units to
- Story mode rewards -
- Event battle rewards - Every now and then there are 3-battle events that award 200 DNA for the first and second battle and usually a card pack as a reward for the third battle.
- Watching ads - If you tap DNA button, a popup will appear with a message "Receive DNA by selling dinosaurs from cages". Two buttons are displayed as options "OK" to dismiss the popup and "Get it free" to watch an add and get some DNA. The button not always work. Even when it does it is limited to a certain number of views per user. So you cannot really farm DNA just by watching ads.
- Selling dinosaurs - I suggest you don't sell dinosaurs for DNA. Even weak dinosaurs might be used for hybrids. If you decide to sell dinosaurs you should sell them at level 1. The DNA you'll get from selling them at higher levels will not pay back the DNA that you'll spend by leveling them up.